# Flutter - How to manage memory with Spritewidget when using a great number of image for a game?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a game with SpriteWidget framework (https://github.com/spritewidget/spritewidget) and I have a lot of assets to mange. I got a random crash during the game since I have increased slightly the number of image assets I use.
Note that the game doesn't crash after image assets loading. I'm able to play a level but when I relaunch an another level I got a crash.
Everything was fine since I have begun the development until yesterday when I have added new level backgrounds and character sprites.

Is there a good pattern to manage asset Image with spritewidget framework ?
- I tried to load everything with ImageMap class at application start
- I tried to load just few asset with ImageMap class at application start and create a new ImageMap at the begin of each level for the level specific Asset (And tried to dispose the Images handled by the ImageMap at the end).
But with the two methods I got a crash when I play two or there games

Thanks in advance for your help
Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a good pattern to manage asset Image with spritewidget
>   framework

Get the TexturePacker tool, pack all your images to 4096x4096 sheets,( or 2048x if you target older devices) . As a result you'll have an image containing all smaller images and a `.json` descriptor.

Feed both to `new SpriteSheet(img,json)`. Access images from sheet by their original names.  This way reduces texture switches during render cycle a lot. If you still experience any crashes try with smaller size of sheet. This is a common practice for any game engine.

Here is a quote from SpriteWidget's docs:

> The most common node type is the Sprite node. A sprite simply draws an
>   image to the screen. Sprites can be drawn from Image objects or
>   SpriteTexture objects. A texture is a part of an Image. Using a
>   SpriteSheet you can pack several texture elements within a single
>   image. This saves space in the device's gpu memory and also make
>   drawing faster. Currently SpriteWidget supports sprite sheets in json
>   format and produced with a tool such as TexturePacker. It's uncommon
>   to manually edit the sprite sheet files. You can create a SpriteSheet
>   with a definition in json and an image:
>
> ```
> SpriteSheet sprites = new SpriteSheet(myImage, jsonCode);
> SpriteTexture texture = sprites['texture.png'];
> ```